# Build a VoIP app in android

Tags: android, sip, voip

I was trying to build a VoIP app with normal app to app call and conference capabilities. I have already achieved this with the help of `Sinch API`. But now I was trying to do it without any 3rd party providers. I looked into several options like `pjsip`,`mjsip` and more but I have no idea how to set them up and integrate them in my app as there is no sample or proper docs for android.

I was going through the google docs and found [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html). I was under the impression that VoIP cannot be implemented without a SIP server, but there was no mention of a server in that page.

In this particular code sample

```
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
builder.setPassword(password);
mSipProfile = builder.build();
```

I had a dilemma. What does the `domain` variable mean to. Also there is no sample app for that (I think it has been removed) Is there any sample available that was implemented based on the docs?

Answer (score 0):

`Domain` name is url of the VoIP provider's registrar server. It's used to make possible registration of the endpoint (device) in the network. It looks like this `sip.linphone.org` and it's part of `SIP URI`.

Comment: Is there any working implementation for this @azimov

Answer (score 0):

In simple words domain is the address of your sip server or an ip of the machine where your Sip server is running and sip server listens on 5060 and 5061 port by default .

There are many openSource sip server that are available on the internet that you can use .For example

[opensips](https://www.opensips.org) can act as Sip registrar,proxy server

[kamailio](https://www.kamailio.org/) can act as Sip registrar,proxy server

[FreeSwitch](https://freeswitch.org/) can act as Sip registrar,A/V conference server,proxy server,IVR a complete PBX

[asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) can act as Sip registrar,proxy server,audio conference server,IVR a complete PBX